# Generate CodeDOM from existing class

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom

I need to add a class (Type) to the CodeNamespace. I have a C# class already written but I don't want to convert it manually to CodeDOM. Is there a way to load an existing into a CodeTypeDeclaration.

It can be runtime or pre-build process.

Comment: what type do you want to add?

Comment: My own. class MyOwn { /*complicated code here*/ }

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @WouterRoos unfortunately no, I had to code by hand found here: https://github.com/jsgoupil/quickbooks-sync/tree/master/src/XsdGenerator however. I would recommend you have a look at Roslyn which would be a better thing to do if you are working on new code.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile code from files using codedom [CompileAssemblyFromSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource.aspx).
I added an example which set the class content and compile it like [here](http://mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/02/treating-c-like-a-scripting-language/).

For more information you can explore for usages of CompileAssemblyFromSource.

Comment: That's a good idea but it is not exactly what I want... I want to load a file directly into the CodeTypeDeclaration so it can be output properly when I call codeProvider.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(..)